# Webpack config creating a dist directory

Tags: webpack

My Webpack config should output 2 bundles to folders assets/js and assets/admin/js. It's working great. However, it is also creating a dist folder with the same directory structure which I don't want. My config is below.

EDIT:

I commented out the output thinking this was the cause. Whether commented out or not the same thing is happening. I'm sure this is the cause of the problem. I'm just not sure how to properly configure the output. I think the Clean Webpack Plugin is creating the directory and needs the output to be properly configured to match the entries.

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  watch: true,

  entry: {
    main: {import: './dev/index.js', filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js'},
    admin: {import:'./dev/admin/index.js', filename: 'admin/js/[name].bundle.js'}
  },

  /*output: {
    //path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
    //filename: '[name].js'
  },*/
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
        },
   
        },
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
            "style-loader",
            // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            "css-loader",
            // Compiles Sass to CSS
            "sass-loader",
          ],
        },
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: It looks like the output config is commented out, so it's running with the default output path which is ./dist, no?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the clean Webpack plugin is causing it. I'm not sure how to properly configure the output so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can always clean with node tools e.g. rimraf (Just add it call to package.json e.g. rimraf myFolder && webpack ...). I am not sure whats wrong with `CleanWebpackPlugin`, but there are always problems with it.